# Migrating content from one to minor version of Drupal 8 to another

Tags: migrations, upgrading

Since Drupal 8 doesn't yet support beta to beta upgrade path(we might be able to upgrade from beta-12 to beta-13 but we are not sure.), has anybody tried migrating  from one minor version to drupal 8 to another version drupal 8?

We are planning to spend 3 man hour months are on a project and just trying to make sure that the efforts won't go waste in case a upgrade path wont be available by the time next beta is released.

Comment: I've tried it and it was a pain. I'd avoid it if things are working or unless you really need a contrib module that's compatible only with another beta.